# Why are police sometimes able to kill without prosecution?

Tags: criminal-law, homicide

I have seen so many stories about cops killing Black Americans (it's not just Blacks, but that is who it usually is) and I found that it is rare for them to actually go to jail. If I killed anybody, I would go straight to jail. But if I were a cop who wanted to kill then I think I would be fine as long as they have that blue on that protects them.

I [read this article on 538](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/baltimore-police-officers-charged-freddie-gray/) and it bothers me to my core. An example is Breonna Taylor, a 26 year old Black woman who was an EMT in Kentucky. Derek Chauvin, a man who is evil in my opinion, is getting a pension payment while children without blue suited parents are starving!

I am asking not out of a rant. I am asking because this is painful to me and my family and I *want answers* from an *objective* legal standpoint. Most cops are not criminals in this way and I am targeting a small minority that sometimes make the news.

Comment: They investigate themselves and decide they did nothing wrong.

Comment: That is crazy. But I thought about it and it makes sense what you said

Comment: *"If I killed anybody, I would go straight to jail."* That depends. Did you kill somebody in obvious self defense? Were you protecting your home/property? Were you performing official duties and had reasonable use of force in performing those duties?